# Monotouch - ipad storyboard project is edited by XCode as Iphone

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, storyboard, xcode4.2

I've upgraded to iOS SDK version 5 , XCode 4.2 , Monodevelop 2.8.1 and monotouch 5.0.

I'm trying to create a new project based on storyboard, I choose "New Solution", "C#", "MonoTouch", "IPad StoryBoard", "SingleView Application".

The solution is created correctly and the first build succeed.

When I edit the .storyboard file XCode opens the Interface builder showing the IPHONE interface 320x480.

I've tried to change this option:
- MonoTouch - Project Options - IPhoneBuild - SDK version  : 5.0
But no luck.

If I run the project from Monodevelop the application is emulated as IPAD.

I've edited the storyboard as source file and it's the IPhone storyboard

If I try to create a standard IPAD project with no storyboard the XCode editor shows the IPAD interface.

Is this a bug in monodevelop?

What steps do I need to follow in order to have the IPAD interface?

Comment: Xamarin confirmed this bug, tracked at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1627

Comment: Fixed and available in the next release